# WooCommerce - include custom fields in the search function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

So I'm looking to include the functionality of displaying content by its custom fields as well as its title and content.

I need to be able to search for orders, as well as subscriptions, on WooCommerce by custom field as well as the normal method. Is there any way I can, without adding additional search forms or booleans, simply get Wordpress to display posts that match with the search term by their custom fields, too?

I have used the following code thanks to a responder on here:

```
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    $custom_fields = array(
        // put all the meta fields you want to search for here
        "gender",
        "birthdate"
    );
    $searchterm = $query->query_vars['s'];

    // we have to remove the "s" parameter from the query, because it will prevent the posts from being found
    $query->query_vars['s'] = "";

    if ($searchterm != "") {
        $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
        foreach($custom_fields as $cf) {
            array_push($meta_query, array(
                'key' => $cf,
                'value' => $searchterm,
                'compare' => '=='
            ));
        }
         $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query);
    };
}
add_filter( "pre_get_posts", "custom_search_query");
```

This works great when searching orders, but what I need to search is subscriptions, where it doesn't work.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes you can , basic ideas is to hook the search action. Quick google search give many way to do it . Sove of them you need to modify based on your need. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/extending-the-search-context-in-the-admin-list-post-screen
https://www.webhostinghero.com/how-to-expand-search-to-custom-fields-in-wordpress/
https://gist.github.com/charleslouis/5924863

Comment: I didn't know how to implement the first example, the second example didn't work, and the third example was for a specific plugin so isn't compatible.

Comment: First example is the one you need. You put those codes in `functions.php` which extends the default query made by wordpress. It mean it tell wordpress that whenever wordpress look/search for posts let him search into post meta or the custom fields too. Hope it helps for your further research. It might not work right away.

Comment: Hi, this worked for WooCommerce orders, but it doesn't work when searching WooCommerce subscriptions?

Comment: It should work, not sure though. Never used subscription so not sure. You need to check where subscription data are stored. In which table of the database and adjust those codes query based on it.

Comment: It works great for orders, but doesn't work at all for subscriptions (which apparently are just special order types). There is no place in the code to edit a table type..

Comment: So subscription is just special order type and all the data stored in same as normal orders? There must be something different which make it not work :S